# How to count different values in a column and same group

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, case-statement

I have to distinguish different values in a group, how do I perform that?
Example of my table:

```
Person  Status
1       Y
2       N
3       Y
3       N
```

-If a person only has `Y` status then display `Yes`

-If a person only has `N` status then display `No`

-If a person has both `Y` and `N` status then display `No`

Result:

```
Person  Status
1       Yes
2       No
3       No
```

How do I perform last logic when a person has both status? Here is the statement I tried which worked but I am not 100% sure if it is accurate:

```
CASE WHEN SUM(CASE WHEN Status = 'Y' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)>=1 AND SUM(CASE WHEN Status = 'N' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)>=1 THEN 'No' 
    WHEN SUM(CASE WHEN Status  = 'Y' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)>=1 THEN 'Yes'
ELSE 'No'END
```

Comment: your statement is correct.it can be simplified though.

Comment: Thank you for the confirmation!

Answer (score 1):

You can use MIN:

```
select CASE WHEN MIN(status) = 'Y' THEN 'Yes' ELSE 'No' END
, Person
from table
group by Person
```

Answer (score 0):

### Checking your query

For simplicity let's say that:

```
(Y) -> SUM(CASE WHEN Status = 'Y' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
(N) -> SUM(CASE WHEN Status = 'N' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
```

So your query can be written as pseudocode:

```
case when (Y)>=1 and (N)>=1 then 'No'
     when (Y)>=1 then 'Yes'
     else 'No'
end
```

To check if your query is correct You need to build a truth table from your query for all possible input:

```
  (Y) | (N)      (Y)>=1 | (N)>=1      (Y)>=1 and (N)>=1      Result
 -----------    -----------------    -------------------    --------
   0  |  0        false | false             false             'No'
   0  | >=1   =>  false | true    =>        false        =>   'No'
  >=1 |  0        true  | false             false             'Yes'
  >=1 | >=1       true  | true              true              'No'
```

Look's like You got it right!

### Creating a correct condition

To be sure if You are making your condition correctly You need to build a truth table:

```
(1)
    Yes   |    No     | Result
-------------------------------
found     | found     | No
not found | found     | No
found     | not found | Yes
not found | not found | Null
```

or

```
(2)
         \       No  
    Yes   \ Found | Not Found |
-------------------------------
 Found     |  No  |    Yes    |
-------------------------------
 Not Found |  No  |    Null   |
 ------------------------------
```

The first thing to notice is that if status==No is found the result is always No.

Only when a No is not found and a Yes is found then we return Yes.

So Your condition can be written with a nested case.

```
select columns, ....
(
  case when (SUM(CASE WHEN Status = 'N' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)>=1) then 'No'
       else case when (SUM(CASE WHEN Status = 'Y' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)>=1) then 'Yes'
                 else NULL
            end
  end
) as result
```

It's easy with 2 variables in a condition.
If You have more variables then I suggest You look into a [Karnaugh map](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Karnaugh_map)

### Checking the 'MIN' answer

Another answer here gave an original solution:

```
select CASE WHEN MIN(status) = 'Y' THEN 'Yes' ELSE 'No' END
, Person
from table
group by Person
```

Is it correct?

Let's check first all the possible input.

```
Input:
{Y} - contains only Y in the column
{N} - contains only N in the column
{Y,N} - contains Y and N in the column
{} - Y and N do not appear in the column
```

Let's calculate all the possible results:

```
Input        MIN(status)      Result
-------     -------------    --------
 {Y}             Y             Yes
 {N}     =>      N        =>   No
 {Y,N}           N             No
 {}             NULL           No
```

It's a correct answer.